# how to refresh part of a site without refreshing the entire page after jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors, page-refresh

I am making a dynamic questions forum and I want to refresh only the listing of the topics when a user ads a new topic , I do not want to refresh the entire page. Is that possible?

This is my markup for the table where the posts are listed:

```
<table class="topics">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%"></th>
        <th width="45%"><a href="">Subject</a></th>
        <th width="15%"><a href="">Author</a></th>
        <th width="10%"><a href="">Replies</a></th>
        <th width="10%"><a href="">Views</a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($discussions as $discussion) : ?>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td><a href=""><img src="<?= site_url('assets/images/featured-posts-icon.png') ?>" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="<?= site_url('discussion/test/' . $discussion->stub) ?>" class="subject"><?php echo $discussion->title; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><?php echo $discussion->author; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $discussion->replies; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $discussion->views; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Markup for adding a new post:

```
<input type="text" name="topic" id="topic" />
<ul class="editor-tools">
    <li class="bold"></li>
    <li class="italic"></li>
    <li class="underscore"></li>
    <li class="list"></li>
    <li class="quote"></li>
</ul>
<textarea id="thread-content"></textarea>
<a href="" class="button create-discussion">Start discussion</a>
```

I am fetching the posts with php. Now when I add a new post with ajax I have the following code:

```
$('a.create-discussion').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('input#topic').val(),
        courseId = 1,
        message = $('textarea#thread-content').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : ROOT_PATH + 'main/ajaxjson/create_discussion',
        data : {title: title, courseId: courseId, message: message},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(result){
        // do something here?
    });
})
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you basically need to PUSH the stuff to the client

you can use these 3 methods

1. from all the pages you can keep making an ajax call to check if a 
        new topic is added (long polling)
2. you can try using COMET
3. there is something called web-sockets in the modern browsers u can give it a try

you can implement long polling like this

```
  window.setInteval("func()",10000);

  function func()
  {
      //ajax call to you server which returns the latest posts
      str = xhr.responseText;

      if(str)
      {
           document.getElementById("id").innerHTML += str;
      }
  }
```

Comment: how can I implement nr 1? any pointers? web-sockets do not work in all browsers

Comment: you can use socketio :) long polling is something like this  u use document.setInterval("func()",10000); call a function which makes an ajax call every 10sec and this function returns the latest question.. i shall edit my answer if you want !!

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side script to generate JUST the markup for the portion of the page you want to 'refresh'.

Then use jQuery to set the inner HTML of that area to what is returned by the server after you've done some work.

PS Tidy up your question, laziness won't do you favours in the future.

Answer (score -2):

You should use instead of done()

```
success:function(){
       // do something here
}
```

like in the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png',
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined' );
  },
  success: function( data ) {
    if (console && console.log){
      console.log( 'Sample of data:', data.slice(0,100) );
    }
  }
});
```

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array**
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status;
>   and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery
>   1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Comment: Actually `success()`, `error()` and `complete()` callbacks will be deprecated for some Ajax functions in jQuery 1.8. To prepare code for their eventual removal in the future there is nothing wrong with using `done()`, `fail()`, and `always()` instead.

Comment: @adeneo thank you for that hint ! I didn't knew that ! But 1.7.1 is currently released, but do you know when 1.8 is being released ?

Comment: Nope! All I know is that it is possible to use the new versions of the Ajax callbacks (has been since 1.6 I believe), and that it says so on jQuery's website. jQuery 1.7 is only a few months old, and 1.7.2rc1 was released last week, so 1.8 will probably not be out for a while yet?

Comment: even if you do not know you should use best practices and best practices are using .done()

Comment: @Mythriel I have never heard or have never read also on SO that .done() is a common use or neither is it a best practices.